# How to change "data/" folder permissions on Galaxy S4 Android KitKat

Tags: android

How to change "data/" folder permissions on Galaxy S4 Android KitKat. I tried to do with adb shell "chmod" command and got an error "Bad mode". I am developing app and i need to see if my app is copying database.db file into dir "data/data/packagename/databases"

Comment: Do you want to change permission of /data directory only or permission of content inside this directory also?

Comment: I need to see all what is inside of "data/", i think yes i need to change permissions for content too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **adb shell chmod 775 /data** command

Comment: I got this error "Unable to chmod /data: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Yes i know, but how? 
my device is not rooted, it's an original firmware on it. Maybe problem is this?

Comment: Yes you need to root your phone first but if you root your phone then your warranty gets void